# Prefix getter and setter with sqldelight

Tags: android, coding-style, sqlbrite, sqldelight

Is it possible to configure sqldelight to prefix all the getters and setters?

```
CREATE TABLE foo {
  bar TEXT 
}
```

<s>bar()</s> -> getBar()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time no, and it's unlikely we'd add it in since its a style choice we made early on. You can do it from the SQLite side by naming your column getBar instead of bar but thats probably not better.

If this is a requirement from some other library I would recommend either changing the column name like mentioned above or creating new methods with the name you want in the implementation that just return the normal method result.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answere. I'm fine with not having getters and setters prefixed. I was just asking because I'm going to refactor a bigger project and wanted to make sure not to miss anything and do unecessary work.